# How to discuss convex/concave behavior of sum of product terms

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If we have function in constraint as $\prod_{i=1}^Nx_i$, $x_i\in[0,1]$, we can take logarithm. Then it can be written as a summation and we can discussion convex/concave behavior of the constraint.

However, I have a constraint as sum of product terms such as $\prod_{i=n_1}^{N_1} x_i+\prod_{i=n_2}^{N_2} x_i+\cdots+\prod_{i=n_M}^{N_M} x_i$ which can be written as in general $\sum_m\prod_{i=n_m}^{N_m} x_i$. In this case, I cannot take the logarithm because of $\sum_m$.

Can someone please guide me what kind of approach I should use?

Answer (score 1):

The function, as you gave it, is neither convex nor concave. However, $\leq$ inequality constraints with this function can be transformed to **convex** constraints given that you know that $x_i > 0$ (note that $x_i$ cannot be zero for this transformation to work).

Assume that you have the constraint (in variables $x,t$):
$$
\prod_{i=n_1}^{N_1} x_i+\prod_{i=n_2}^{N_2} x_i+\cdots+\prod_{i=n_M}^{N_M} x_i \leq t
$$
By adding auxiliary variables $t_1, \dots, t_M$ you can transform it to the following equivalent system of inequalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^M t_j &\leq t \\
\prod_{i=n_j}^{N_j} x_i &\leq t_j, \quad j = 1, \dots, M
\end{aligned}
$$
You can make another transformation by making a change of variables $x_i = \exp(y_i)$, which is possible since $x_i > 0$, and get the following system:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^M t_j &\leq t \\
\exp\left(\sum_{i=n_j}^{N_j} y_i\right) &\leq t_j, \quad j = 1, \dots, M
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, you can take the logarithm on both sides in the $\exp$ constraints, and get the following convex inequalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^M t_j &\leq t \\
\sum_{i=n_j}^{N_j} y_i - \ln(t_j) &\leq 0, \quad j = 1, \dots, M
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I really appreciate your effort !!! Actually, in my case, I cannot avoid $x_i=0$, which frequently happens in my system.

Comment: Then you cannot take logarithm  at all, since $\log(0)$ is undefined. Do you have a lot of variables? Is it feasible, in your case, to check all possible combinations of zeros?

Comment: I am looking for a general formulation so that no. of parameters may be changed. The original (application water-flow) problem looks like $\left(\frac{1-x_m}{1-x_m+b_m}\right)\sum_{n}a_{m}\left(\prod_{j\in J_{m,n}}x_j\right) \geq t$ where $a_m$ and $b_m$ are positive constants. Even if I assume $x_i>0$, I was not able to show that this is a convex constraint due to the term $\frac{1-x_m}{1-x_m+b_m}$. Is that right? If this is possible, I may assume $x_i>0$, it can be very small in some stages, etc.

Comment: In your case, where the constraint is $\geq$, I believe it cannot be formulated as a convex constraint at all.

Answer (score 0):

Each product has an indefinite Hessian and so is neither concave no convex. The sum will be neither concave nor convex. (The product and sum are linear in each individual $x_i$ though.)

If your constraint is of the form $g(x)\leq 0$ and you want a convex constraint set, then it is enough that $g$ is quasiconvex. If your constraint is of the form $g(x)\geq 0$, then it is enough that $g$ is quasiconcave. In your case, each product is quasiconcave so long as $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ (I am not sure about the sum).

To show each individual product is quasiconcave, note that $$\prod_{i=1}^Nx_i=\exp\sum_{i=1}^N \ln x_i.$$ The sum is concave because each $\ln x_i$ is concave. It follows that the product is quasiconcave because it is a monotonic transformation of a concave function.

Comment: Is there a way of proving it? thanks !!!

Comment: Sorry, reconsidering it I may be wrong. Each individual product is quasiconcave, but I am not sure about the sum (since sums of quasiconcave functions are not necessarily quasiconcave). You can prove it using the definition of quasiconcavity or using the bordered Hessian..

Comment: Yes, each term means the very first function I gave. However, I need the sum of products.